# Big delay with JQuery animate on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have 2 divs floating to the left and right of my main content. I want to shrink the divs if the user shrinks their browser window, so they dont cover the content. Conversly, I want them to expand again if the user makes the window big enough.

To do this, I have created the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var windowwidth = $(window).width();

  if(windowwidth < 1400){
    $('#sliderholder').animate({width:'25px'});
    $('#contactholder').animate({width:'25px'});
  }

  if(windowwidth > 1400){
    $('#sliderholder').animate({width:'222px'});
    $('#contactholder').animate({width:'222px'});
  }

});
```

But this doesnt work properly - the animations seem to occur at random, or are very much delayed.

Would anyone know how to improve this?

EDIT: did some experimenting and have found it is delayed, rather then out of synch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `.stop()` to the above and it seems to solve it.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var windowwidth = $(window).width();

  if(windowwidth < 1400){
    $('#sliderholder').stop().animate({width:'25px'});
    $('#contactholder').stop().animate({width:'25px'});
  }

  if(windowwidth > 1400){
    $('#sliderholder').stop().animate({width:'222px'});
    $('#contactholder').stop().animate({width:'222px'});
  }

});
```

Comment: Well .. i just wasted a few hours of my life. O.o What a simple fix .